# Finding triplets in CUDA kernel

Tags: cuda

I have `p.ntp` test particles and every `i`-th particle has Cartesian coordinates `tp.rh[i].x`, `tp.rh[i].y`, `tp.rh[i].z`. Within this set I need to find CLUSTERS. It means, that I am looking for particles closer to the `i`-th particle less than `hill2 (tp.D_rel < hill2)`. The number of such a members is stored in `N_conv`.

I use this cycle `for (int i = 0; i < p.ntp; i++)`, which goes through the data set. For each `i`-th particle I calculate squared distances `tp.D_rel[idx]` relative to the others members in the set. Then I use first thread `(idx == 0)` to find the number of cases, which satisfy my condition. At the end, If are there more than 1 (`N_conv > 1`) positive cases I need to write out all particles forming possible cluster together (triplets, ...).

My code works well only in cases, where `i < blockDim.x`. Why? Is there a general way, how to find clusters in a set of data, but write out only triplets and more?

Note: I know, that some cases will be found twice.

```
__global__ void check_conv_system(double t, struct s_tp tp, struct s_mp mp, struct s_param p, double *time_step)
{
const uint bid = blockIdx.y * gridDim.x + blockIdx.x;
const uint tid = threadIdx.x;
const uint idx = bid * blockDim.x + tid;
double hill2 = 1.0e+6;

__shared__ double D[200];
__shared__ int ID1[200];
__shared__ int ID2[200];

if (idx >= p.ntp) return;
int N_conv;

for (int i = 0; i < p.ntp; i++)
 {

   tp.D_rel[idx] = (double)((tp.rh[i].x - tp.rh[idx].x)*(tp.rh[i].x - tp.rh[idx].x) +
                          (tp.rh[i].y - tp.rh[idx].y)*(tp.rh[i].y - tp.rh[idx].y) +
                          (tp.rh[i].z - tp.rh[idx].z)*(tp.rh[i].z - tp.rh[idx].z));
    __syncthreads();
    N_conv = 0;

    if (idx == 0)
    {

      for (int n = 0; n < p.ntp; n++) {
       if ((tp.D_rel[n] < hill2) && (i != n)) {

         N_conv = N_conv + 1;
         D[N_conv] = tp.D_rel[n];
         ID1[N_conv] = i;
         ID2[N_conv] = n;

        }
       }

       if (N_conv > 0) {
         for(int k = 1; k < N_conv; k++) {
           printf("%lf %lf %d %d \n",t/365.2422, D[k], ID1[k], ID2[k]);
          }
        }

      } //end idx == 0

    } //end for cycle for i          

 }
```

Comment: for questions asking "why isn't this code working?" you are supposed to provide a [mcve].  A kernel, by itself, is not a MCVE.

Answer (score 1):

As RobertCrovella mentionned, without an MCV example, it is hard to tell.

However, the `tp.D_del` array seems to be written to with `idx` index, and read-back after a `__syncthreads()` with full range indexing `n`. Note that the call to `__syncthreads()` will only perform synchronization within a block, not accross the whole device. As a result, some thread/block will access data that has not been calculated yet, hence the failure.

You want to review your code so that values computed by blocks do not depend one-another.